# FROM input type="date" value TO a Php variable

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want to "save" the value of  into a php variable, so if in the "datebox" there is something like *11/02/2016*, I want to save this value on `$date`, then I can do `echo $date;` and see again *11/02/2016*.
**the datepicker is important**

I tried on two ways:

1.

```
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST">
    <!-- Today date -->
    <input type="date" name="today" value="<?php echo date("Y-m-d");?>">
</form>
</body>
```

```
<?php
    $date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_POST['today']));
    echo "Today is $date";
?>
```

This output: Today is 1970-01-01

2.

```
<head>
<script>
function myFunction() {
    var date = document.getElementById("today").value;
    document.getElementById("here").innerHTML = date;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST">
    <input type="date" name="today" value="<?php echo date("Y-m-d");?>">
    <input type="hidden" id="here" name="this">
</form>
</body>
```

```
<?php

    $data = $_POST['this']));
    echo "Today is $data";

?>
```

This output: Today is

Can anybody help me please?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: RTFM: http://php.net/date You didn't specify the second argument, so by default date() will use `time()`, which means you're generating a "now" date, always.

Comment: @BesjanVeizi What do you want to achieve? Do you want to format your date in dd/mm/yy or do you want the date to always be today?

Comment: because I just want to show by default the date of today

Comment: I want that every date I choose can be saved in a php format

Comment: the datepicker is extremly important

Comment: Edited my answer to include html code you need

Comment: changed the $_POST value, accidentaly put date instead of today

Answer (score 1):

Submit Element is missing from your form which means form is not processing anything.So put submit button to process the form.Try this code.

```
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST">
<input type="date" name="today" value="<?php echo date("Y-m-d");?>">
<input type="submit" name="a">
</form>
</body>
if(isset($_POST['a']))
{
  $date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_POST['today']));
  echo "Today is $date";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the built in function DateTime you can do

```
date_default_timezone_set("Europe/London"); //Set your timezone
$dateNow = new DateTime;

echo $dateNow->format('d/m/Y'); // Will echo 11/02/2016
```

http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php for a list of supported timezones

EDIT:
Including your HTML:

```
<?php 
    date_default_timezone_set("Europe/London"); //Set your timezone
    $date = new DateTime;
?>

<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST">
    <!-- today date-->
    <input type="date" name="today" value="<?php echo $date->format('Y-m-d'); ?>">
    <input type="submit" name="test" value="test">
</form>
```

Then later on:

```
<?php
    $datePOST = new DateTime($_POST['today']);
    echo $datePOST->format('d/m/Y');
?>
```

I hope this is what you were looking for.

Comment: I tried your code and it works only for the actual date (the last echo prints only the date of today). When I change date on the datapicker the echo doesn't update...any idea to update the output string?

Comment: I added the code, with a submit button on my website : http://themooliecommunity.com/Solo/test.php Can you check if that is what you need? I have also update the code to include the submit button

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a submit element, and you have a coercion to null / 0 in your output.  The result of the first is that you never submit anything.  So your form doesn't actually process anything, a form does nothing until it's actually submitted.

Your second error results in the code always outputting the Unix Epoch, which is what a timestamp with an int result of 0 is.  You need to turn on your errors for whatever server you're using.  Turning off errors or suppressing them seems like a good idea, but it causes a host of easy-to-fix problems to remain undiagnosed.

This code should work on PHP 5.4 and above.

```
<?php
     $self = isset($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) ? $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] : '#';
     $now = date("Y-m-d");
     $today = isset($_POST['today']) ? $_POST['today'] : (new DateTime)->format('Y-m-d');
     $date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($today));
     $formattedResult = "Today is $date";
?>
    <form action="<?= $self; ?>" method="POST">

    <input type="date" name="today" value="<?= $today;?>">
    <button type='submit' >
        You must submit the form to process it
        </button>
</form>
<?= $formattedResult;?>
</body>
```